# Why Can't I Use An Array in a Switch Statement in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I've written a program that generates 1,000 random numbers in the range of 1-10. What I then want it to do is tell me how many times each number was produced. But, for some reason why I run this program, I get 0 for every number.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void print(const int array[], int limit);

#define SIZE 1000
int main(void)
{
int i;
int arr[SIZE];

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;

print(arr,SIZE);

return 0;
}

void print(const int array[], int limit)
{ 
int index, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0,         
count7 = 0, count8 = 0, count9 = 0, count10 = 0;

for (index = 0; index < limit; index++)
{
    switch (array[index])
    {
        case '1' : count1++;
                  break;
        case '2' : count2++;
                  break;
        case '3' : count3++;
                  break;
        case '4' : count4++;
                  break;
        case '5' : count5++;
                  break;
        case '6' : count6++;
                  break;
        case '7' : count7++;
                  break;
        case '8' : count8++;
                  break;
        case '9' : count9++;
                  break;
        case '10' : count10++;
                 break;
        default : break;
    }

}
 printf("There were %d 10s, %d 9s, %d 8s, %d 7s, %d 6s, %d 5s, %d 4s, %d 3s, %d 2s, %d                         
 1s.", count10, count9, count8, count7, count6, count5, count4, count3, count2, count1);
}
```

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`...

Comment: You aren't "using the array" in the switch statement. You're using the value at a particular index. Consider `int x = array[index]; switch(x) ..` - so, what's the problem? Naught to do with arrays in switch statements ..

Comment: `'1'` = 49, for starters.

Comment: "for starters" - is there anything else I need to know? i took off the quotes and now it runs fine

Comment: Instead of `count1` etc, use an array `int count[10];` and `for(i = 0; i < limit; ++i) { count[array[i]]++; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the single quotes around the numbers in the case statement. You are creating character literals by including the single quotes. Just take them off and you'll have integer literals, which is what you intend.

Comment: Ah, for some reason i never thought about why there were single quotes vs. no quotes. thank you *slaps forehead*

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing numbers (stored in array) to character literals '1', '2', etc. In addition it would probably be easier to implement print using an array:

```
void print(const int array[], int limit)
{ 
    int index;
    int count[11] = {0};

    for (index = 0; index < limit; index++)
    {
        count[array[index]]++;
    }
    printf("There were %d 10s", count[10]);
    for (index = 10; index > 0; index--)
    {
        printf(" %d %ds%c", count[index], index, (index > 1)?',':'.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use some of those techniques because we haven't learned them yet.

Comment: No worries, do what you feel comfortable with. As far as I can tell the only thing here you have not already used is the Ternary operation (a?b:c), which is basicly an inline way of writing an if statment.

Comment: Actually I have learned that, but I guess I'm confused by how you are using it. Why would you want to end the sentence in a comma?